# Will Linux work on this laptop

Tags: linux, laptop

I believe Linux may not work on all laptops. Will it work on following [Hewlett Packard laptop](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-mini-210-2000-pc-series/4247645)?

```
HP Mini 210-2000
Intel Atom (TM) CPU N475 @ 1.83 GHz
2 Gb RAM
```

I am especially interested in installing Debian Stable Linux on it. If that is not possible, which Linux distribution is best suited for this. Thanks for your help.

Edit:
I am especially concerned if there will be any problem in using **touchpad** with Linux with this (relatively low spec) laptop?

Comment: The RAM is on the low side, so you should look for a lightweight 32-bit Debian derivative. Run a Live Boot first, and this will give you a good impression of the performance you can expect. K. Robert's quoted specs below seem decidedly low for current releases, but he doesn't cite his TecMint link, so I can't verify whether it's outdated information. With only 2GB of RAM you will need swapping. If disc space is limited, use a [swap file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_a_swap_file.3F) instead of a swap partition, though you won't be able to hibernate.

Comment: Linux can work pretty much anywhere, as long as you have drivers

Comment: Pl see edit in my question above.

Comment: The Debian web site identifies the hardware requirements.  In the image at your link, that looks like a standard laptop touchpad.  The only way to get a real feel for how well it will work is to try a live session.  2 GB isn't much RAM.  Debian will run in it, but you probably want to do some actual work in addition to running the OS.  There are a bunch of lightweight distros based on Debian Stable that might be a better starting point than the Debian general purpose distro, which will have a lot of bloat unless you start with their minimal distro and build your own.  (cont'd)

Comment: The desktop environment you pick will make a big difference. Without knowing what you need to do with it and your preferences, it would be way too broad to try to make recommendations, and that's off-topic, anyway.

Comment: For desktop environment, I would like to use XFCE. My second choice is LXDE.

Comment: Two popular distros to check out based on Debian Stable: [Sparky Linux](https://sparkylinux.org/about/) is a lightweight with LXDE or LXQT.  [MX Linux](https://mxlinux.org/current-release-features/) is a mid-weight with XFCE.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search can help you with this in future. It looks like according to tecmint.com the minimum for  your specified Linux the requirementss are:
Minimum RAM: 256MB.
Recommended RAM: 512MB.
Hard Drive space: 10 GB.
Minimum 1GHz Pentium processor
So you can indeed run it on the laptop you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Create a live distro, try to boot it without installing, and see if hardware (sound card, wifi) gets recognized and if there exist additional drivers/configuration.

I would suggest Lubuntu or Puppy Linux for this configuration.